# Is it possible to store form data and div contents with cookies?

Tags: cookies

I'm trying to store a few variables which users will generally have to retype to cookies, or some other form of information storage, so that next time the user goes to that web page all the information they inputted last time would be.

So if someone put in

"Example name", when they return then "Example name" will automatically be filled in the input id "name".

Also, there are a few dynamic divs, which append content based on what is in on the page, and what the user has already inputted.

So is there any way to save this information, as there can be a lot (no more than about 100kb or so, that needs saving), that the user can come back to and add more/edit/etc. without having to redo it all?

Answer (score 0):

Gonna answer my own question, if that's alright

```js
if(!localStorage.getItem('userjson')) {
  populateStorage();
} else {
  setStyles();
}
function populateStorage() {
  localStorage.setItem('userjson', $('#userJSON').html());
  localStorage.setItem('see', $('#see').html());

  setStyles();
}

function setStyles() {
  var Userjson = localStorage.getItem('userjson');
  var See = localStorage.getItem('see');

  $('#userJSON').append(Userjson);
  $('#see').append(See);
}
```

Found local storage has a lot more space, and is a lot easier to work with. And seeing as I honestly don't give a damn about users who use an outdated browser (as we are dealing with something that expects a semi-tech savvy user) this is fine